# AWS Lambda times out on 30 seconds even though timeout configured to be 2 minutes

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS Lambda function written in C# which:

- is triggered by a message on a SQS queue
- makes 2 (slow/long duration) HTTP REST calls to external (non-AWS) services
- sends a message to an SQS Queue

I have configured the Lambda Basic Settings Timeout to 2 minutes.
[image]

However, if 2 HTTP REST calls take more than 30 seconds the Lambda times out:
[image]

Here is the relevant code, you can see the aligned log statements in the code and logs:

```
        static void get1()
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Before get1");
            var task = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync("http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/35000/url/http://www.google.co.uk"));
            Console.WriteLine("get1 initiated, about to wait");
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("get1 wait complete");

            var result = task.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("After get1, result: " + result.StatusCode);
        }
```

This service http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/35000/url/http://www.google.co.uk, just delays for 35000 milliseconds then provides a response from "http://www.google.co.uk".

If the HTTP REST calls take less than 30 seconds, the Lambda completes and writes a message to the output SQS queue. In this example, I changed the delay/sleep durations to 5 seconds instead of 35 seconds, so the total execution time was less than 30 seconds:
[image]

In case the issue was somehow related to the usage of C# GetAsync / task.Wait(), I just tested and found the same timeout behaviour if I instead call:

```
        static void sleepSome(int durationInSeconds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("About to sleep for " + durationInSeconds + " seconds");

            Thread.Sleep(durationInSeconds * 1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Sleep over");

        }
```

Which gives me log output of:
[image]

I am wondering if I should use an AWS SDK API from within my Lambda to log to console the configured timeout, just to prove that the timeout I have configured is "active/valid/heeded" etc.

The full end to end orchestration here, in case it is relevant is:

- Postman Test client ->
- AWS API GW ->
- AWS Lambda1 ->
- AWS SQS ->
- AWS Lambda2 ->

  - REST API Calls
- AWS SQS

AWS Lambda2 is the one that is timing out prematurely, and shown in the logs.

I only seem to have a single version:
[image]

And a single alias:
[image]

Comment: Is your lambda function in VPC?

Comment: No, I just created it, without doing any VPC configuration. There are VPC's in the AWS Account, but I guess/assume they are not relevant if I did not explicitly do anything during the configuration/creation of this Lambda to specify a VPC, is that right? How can I know for sure?

Comment: If you haven't explicitly set your lambda to be in VPC, then it is not in one. The other possibility is that some websites block AWS ip ranges, to avoid scraping. Maybe this is what you are experiencing now?

Comment: As shown in one of the screen shots, the external website works fine when I set the duration/sleep to be 5 seconds instead of 35 seconds, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: @MattG Are you using Lambda alias or versions? CloudWatch logs show $LATEST version is invoked, is that the one with the 2 min timeout?

Comment: @Paradigm I have not configured any Lambda alias or version. How can I be 100% certain. Which AWS Console output will prove it?

Comment: For Lambda versions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html

Comment: @Paradigm, I have included some screen shots of my alias's and versions, there only seems to be one of each.

Comment: @MattG Try printing the remaining time ("RemainingTime") from the context variable inside the handler at the start: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-context.html

Answer (score 0):

While Lambda itself has a 2 minute timeout, the timeout you see occurring might actually be due to the AWS API Gateway limit of 30 seconds. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: Hi @kenny, the Lambda that times out is invoked by SQS, an earlier Lambda in the chain is invoked by API GW, but that Lambda successfully sends a request to SQS and sends a HTTP response to the initial caller (Postman in this case) within the 30 second API GW timeout.